# Timestamp range in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-arithmetic

I am simply trying get results within a specific timestamp range. I am given only the dates so I append '00:00:01' to the from-date and '23:59:59' to the to-date.

I've tried

```
WHERE DATE_SENT > (to_timestamp($P{FROM_DATE}||'00:00:01'))
DATE_SENT < (to_timestamp($P{TO_DATE}||'23:59:59'))
```

and

```
WHERE DATE_SENT BETWEEN (to_timestamp($P{FROM_DATE}||'00:00:01')) AND (to_timestamp($P{TO_DATE}||'23:59:59'))
```

However, neither seem to work. If both from- and to- dates are the same date I simply get no data. And when I use to_date and drop the time section, use <= and >= and the two dates are the same, I get no results again.

I read that 'BETWEEN' is inclusive but I don't see that in my results. The table field is actually timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the field is in fact a timestamp since you are only seeming to be dealing with granularity to the second which is fully supported by the DATE datatype.

Second, when it comes to conversions to DATE or TIMESTAMP, making assumptions on the default format being used by the NLS setup is a bad idea, as is counting on any sort of implicit conversions affected by format. And bear in mind that the Timestamp datatype includes fractional seconds. So if it IS a timestamp column and not a date, and if you are getting your date as a string in format 'YYYY/MM/DD', then do something like:

to_timestamp($P{FROM_DATE}||' 00:00:01.000000','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')

to make sure that it is casting your string to the correct date.

What is probably happening is that the string parameter and your default date format are out of sync, so the timestamp it is determining is not within the range of your data.

And if the underlying field is a DATE, then the same approach applies - just use TO_DATE instead of TO_TIMESTAMP and adjust the format mask appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **BETWEEN** includes the **upper** and **lower** ranges of the between condition.

The problem seems to be the missing **Format Model**, due to which your **locale-specific client NLS settings** might be applied, thus showing incorrect behaviour.

Also, you could simply use **TO_DATE** rather than **TO_TIMESTAMP** as a date data type has both date and time elements.

```
WHERE   DATE_SENT 
BETWEEN TO_DATE($P{from_date}||'00:00:01', '<date_format>HH24:MI:SS') 
AND     TO_DATE($P{to_Date}  ||'23:59:59',''<date_format>HH24:MI:SS')
```

Make sure you put the correct `<date_format`, for example, `'MM/DD/YYYY'`.

You could also use the [**ANSI Timestamp Literal**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) if your date format is known to you in advance as **YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS**

```
WHERE   DATE_SENT 
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '$P{from_date}'||'00:00:01' 
AND     TIMESTAMP '$P{to_Date}'  ||'23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the dates!  There is no reason to fiddle with the time component, when you can just use inequalities on the dates:

```
WHERE DATE_SENT >= to_timestamp($P{FROM_DATE})
      DATE_SENT < to_timestamp($P{TO_DATE}) + 1
```

Or, in you prefer, `+ interval 1 day`.

Comment: `TO_DATE` and `TO_TIMESTAMP[_TZ]` functions should almost always (as is always) include a format mask to avoid bugs caused by variations in the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and/or `NSL_TIMESTAMP[_TZ]_FORMAT` settings.